# Can I specify a port when connecting to a Windows share?

Tags: networking, samba, share

I have a network setup like this  (Windows File Server) <-> (Windows Gateway) <-> (Workstation).

I am trying to allow the Workstation to access a share on the Windows File Server.

I was playing around using netsh interface portproxy on the Gateway to redirect traffic from port 4025 to the File Server port 445, but I can't get this to work.

I was hoping to be able to use \GatewayIP:4025\fileServerShareFolder in Windows explorer on my workstation, but that seems like a dead end. I am open to other solutions.

Comment: I am afraid that port 445 is not enough for Windows Share : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731402.aspx and http://superuser.com/questions/764623/what-port-or-ports-are-used-for-file-sharing-in-windows

Comment: I had seen this previously, but I interpreted that to mean I could just turn off netbios and use 445 exclusively. Regardless, I am guessing there is no way to configure these ports on the client before connecting to a file share server?